# What magic items and feats improve a Monk's attack bonus?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, feats, monk

The Stone Fist Monk character in my group has a relatively low attack bonus because she didn't get a really high main ability score.

I'm wondering what feats and magic items, other than magic weapons +1, can increase a monk's accuracy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a note, if the monk doesn't have at least an 16 (and that's absurdly low) after post-racial bonuses, it may be best to consider having a chat with the player and the DM saying "D&D doesn't like it when primary stats suck. What can we do to fix this?"

Feats:

- Superior Implement Proficiency: Accurate Dagger/Ki Focus
- Implement Expertise (Light Blades/Ki Focus)
- Deadly Draw (Get CA on enemies slid adjacent is better for centered breath, but there are a number of ways for stone-fist to take advantage of it)
- Nimble Blade (if you're going with Light blades. Great synergy with *all* of the above)

Items:

- Learning Weapon: gain a bonus to attack every time you miss the same enemy. Restricts the monk from using her AoEs, but when you're playing catch-up like this, most everything gets sacrificed.

General strategy:

- Combat Advantage, Combat Advantage, Combat Advantage. When you're not hitting, flanking or other CA granting means are your friend.
- Teamwork: Get the leader of the group to boost your attack modifer (she should be doing this anyways) or debuff enemy defenses.)